# What's roughly analogous to a cocos2D Scene in iOS-UIKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

In cocos2D the experience of the user is broken into Scenes. Menu Scenes, perhaps some Option Scenes, Game Level Scenes, Credits, etc. A Director shuffles the user through these scenes as needed. There's transitions of various sorts between those Scenes.

In iOS, (not Sprite Kit) what's the equivalent of a Scene called, and what are the names/types of transitions available between them? And what's the equivalent of a Director?

EDIT: In the following video of Storyboards, the term Scene is used for what appear to be similar to how they might be thought of by the user within a cocos2D application, and Segues is used to describe what look an awful lot like transitions. Is this a common lexicon for such things in UIKit/iOS?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_DCTSTv1Mw

Comment: In iOS there is no concept like scene, there we use separate view for different scene.

Comment: So a View is like a Scene?

Comment: @SKOOP: Not quite - a View is a view. You can have several views running at the same time - unlike scenes, which can only run once at a time. Some applications use only one view at a time, so you might find it analogous to scenes, but they are fundamentally different.

Comment: @Just Kidding. Thanks! See my "answer" below for more info on what I've gleaned so far. I had a couple of questions about Seques and UIViewControllers, but I've been blocked from asking more questions. And can't possibly contribute to the site because I'm not at that stage of knowledge. So...

Answer (score 1):

SpriteKit is a part of iOS, just a heads up.

So really what you are asking is "in `UIKit` what is the closest thing to a `CCScene`?"

`UIView` is the closest thing you can get. But it doesn't provide the same type of interface as a game engine like Cocos2d/SpritKit would.

The [class reference for UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView%3atoView%3aduration%3aoptions%3acompletion%3a) has a few methods that encapsulate transitions to other `UIViews`. Namely:

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
+ (void)transitionWithView:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

For the animation option, you can provide the following type of transitions:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve   = 5 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop     = 6 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom  = 7 << 20,
```

In this instance. A `UIViewController` would be the best thing you could use in place of a `CCDirector`. However, an application doesn't typically have just 1 `UIViewController`. `UIKit` and `SpriteKit` are meant for two very different things, thus they are used in different ways.

A view controller would cause the transition like this (assuming you have some action method):

```
-(IBAction)switchViewsPressed:(id)sender {
     [UIView transitionFromView:[self firstView] toView:[self secondView] duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: So a UIView can be made of a tonne of other UIViews, but one of them is kind of the "Scene" for the rest of them?

Comment: And does a UIViewController stipulate what kind of transition occurs between any two views? Or do views do this themselves?

Comment: Kinda. This is why there is no 1:1 relation for Scene:View. A `UIViewController` has a `UIView` that can be referenced via `[self view]`. This would be the "Scene", then instead of `CCNodes`, you add more `UIView`s to the view controllers view.

Comment: The `UIViewController` does not stipulate the transition directly through anything like a block or delegate interface. Instead, you would code the transition in the `UIViewController` to cause the transition of the views. Check edit to answer for an example.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? It sounds like you have a Cocos2D background, and not an iOS. This can change things drastically based on your end goal.

Comment: I'm trying to learn what these things are called in iOS so I can begin researching the equivalents of transitions, scenes and the director of cocos2D. Specifically, I'd like to know how to build a "scene", and transition from one to another... but without the terms for these things it's very hard to get a conceptual understanding of them in iOS.

Comment: Yea, but the point being that UIKit is not the same thing as the Cocos2D engine, it doesn't behave the same way or have the same view hierarchy.

Comment: For instance, all of the "Menu Scenes, perhaps some Option Scenes, Game Level Scenes, Credits, etc." would each be their own view controller. And you would use a UINavigationController to transition between them.

Comment: "Yea, but the point being that UIKit is not the same thing as the Cocos2D engine, it doesn't behave the same way or have the same view hierarchy." -- Of course it doesn't behave the same way... that's why I'm asking "what's the EQUIVALENT?" -- It's obvious it's not going to be the same, but roughly, what's the name, role etc of those things that do SIMILAR things?

Comment: I've found some use of Scenes, see edited question, in a video about Storyboards, and curious about its acceptance as language for such things.

Comment: in your example code that follows "A view controller would cause the transition like this..." couldn't this code exist just about anywhere, briefly making ANYTHING into a "view controller"?

Comment: A view controller refers to `UIViewController`, or any subclass. You can say anything "controls" your view. And the problem with providing "equivalents" means that you would be designing your UIKit application the same way as a Cocos2D application. Now, if you are making a game or something, you could do this, but a typical application should not be designed with the same concepts in mind.

Comment: This is not about doing, it's about learning the reference points to learn where to start understanding how to do "it" (or anything else) in UIKit the way the framework intends it to be done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, now that I know some of the terminology:

A UIView is a rectangular object that can act like a Scene in that it holds all the other UIViews that make up the objects of a "Scene". So, in a cocos2D sense, One UIView is the Scene, other UIViews are the Nodes that make up the contents of a Scene.

Inside UIViews is a Layer, essentially a CALayer, but others can be placed in as children of this Layer and also act as Nodes from cocos2D, but they're all going to be Children of the UIView container they're in.  In this sense all UIViews can be thought of as cocos2D Scenes, the major difference being that UIKit permits many UIViews whereas cocos2D only permits one current and active Scene.

Just about anything seems able to tell a UIView to transition to another UIView.

So assigning one UIView the role of being a master UIView for all the other UIViews that make up the Scene means it's "THE Scene".  This "master" UIView would be assigned a UIViewController that could then inform transitions between it and other "master" UIViews, but this could also be the case for "sub-Scenes" made up of other View(s).

In this sense UIViewController can act like a Director, but it also does other things. Not sure what, at this stage. But any other object can also tell a UIView to transition to another UIView, so anything can be a Director.